# Rotativa with Asp.net Core 6.0 not working, getting error : System.Exception: QWin32PrintEngine

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

I am using library `Rotativa.AspNetCore` (1.2.0) for generating PDF's in my project, getting the below error intermittently (not all the times) while generating PDF, could someone please help me, how to resolve the issue?. I am using .NET Core 6.0. It was working fine on .NET Core 3.1, but this issue is appearing intermittently in .NET 6.0:

> Error: Exception "System.Exception: QWin32PrintEngine::initialize: OpenPrinter failed (The RPC server is unavailable.)
>
> at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(String wkhtmlPath, String switches, String html, String wkhtmlExe)
> at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)
> at Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ActionContext context)
> at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.BuildFile(ActionContext context)

I tired to downgrad `Rotativa.AspNetCore` to version 1.1.1 and upgraded the version to 1.2.0-beta both cases getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe you can try to restart the project.

Comment: I am running the app locally for testing.